# Generate a code for records in data base

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm facing problem which I can't name so its hard to google it! :)
Technological stack of my project is Java 8, Spring Boot 2.0.0.M4, MongoDB 3.4.7

So what I would like to ask You:

In my web application I need generate a code for records in data base. 
Code should look like this YYMMDD0001 (1709290001) first part YYMMDD is easy.
But what about second part 0001 and then 0002 - 9999. The problem is, I have many users, so this number have to be shared. Number also must be reset every next day to 0001. If I'll restart server I have to get last value back. It's obvious that for this I'll have to create kind of a document in MongoDB.

Maybe You know some good approach how to do this, to make it possible to work with many users.
What is a popper name for such approach?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Start here:
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/

Then expand the code to track a stored date along with the seq num.  The vendNextId() function will call date() and if the date crosses into the next day, reset the seq to 0 and set the stored date to the new date.